# F# fsharp Fast way of finding a string "starting with" from two arrays

Tags: arrays, performance, parallel-processing, f#

I have a problem with performance in large arrays (50k each). What would be the fastest way of finding a string that starts with another string given two arrays? I'm have tried different things, but the code below seems to be as good as I can get it.

```
let findFile (f:string, p:string, pc:string, pcn:string) =
    f.StartsWith(p + "-" + pc) || 
    f.StartsWith(p + "_" + pc) ||
    f.StartsWith(p + "-" + pcn) ||
    f.StartsWith(p + "_" + pcn)

products
|> Array.Parallel.map (fun i p ->
    allFiles |> Array.Parallel.map (fun f ->
        if findFile (f.Filename, p.Style, p.ColorCode, p.ColorName)
        then {p with Filename = f.Filename }
        else p
    ))
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you profiled this for the bottleneck?

Comment: can you give a worked example...you have 2 arrays and you seem to be taking the product of them so the combinations are 50,000 * 50,000 which is a big number...you're donig this 4 times (in the find file), and really assuming most things dont match, just looking for p,,,before looking for pc and pcn, should make it 4 times quicker

Comment: @s952163 I have not profiled yet, I haven't figured out how to do it.

Comment: @MrD yes, it's big number of iterations. And you are correct the match is fuzzy. I'm trying AMieres's regex suggestion right now. Will post results. 

Thank you all again for your support.

Comment: In Visual Studio there is  a Debug | Performance Profiler menu.

Comment: @s952163 I am currently on a mac and using dotnet core with VScode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I would recommend to sanitize the filenames by splitting the two parts and if possible removing the rest:

- Split the filenames by the `'-'`or `'_'` character so you compare tuples of (style * color) instead of strings twice. Also if at all possible, differentiate between when using color code from color name and separate into 2 arrays.

Now you have 2 options: use a Dictionary or sort the values

- Dictionary: take the longer list and put it in a dictionary. Scan the shorter list looking for the values. Dictionaries use hash tables which make them very efficient and comparisons are also very fast. This requires that you use as a key only the style and color code/name leaving the rest of the string out.

The solution could look like this:

```
let dict () =
    let dict = new Dictionary<_, _>()
    allFiles |> Seq.iter (fun f -> f.Filename.Split '-' |> fun a -> dict.Add((a.[0], a.[1]), f) )
    products
    |> Array.Parallel.map (fun p -> 
        let vRef = ref { Filename = "" }
        if dict.TryGetValue((p.Style, p.ColorCode) , vRef)
        then {p with Filename = (!vRef).Filename }
        else p
    )
```

If that is not possible consider then:

- Sorting both lists: products and filenames. Scan both ordered lists simultaneously with an index each only advancing the lower value each time.

One more thing:
If you still want to do string comparisons you should consider using compiled Regex which are very efficient. Your regex could be something like: `^code[-_](red|FF0000)` which would match any of the 4 values:

- `code-red`
- `code_red`
- `code-FF0000`
- `code_FF0000`

This is how you use compiled Regex:

```
let regex = new Regex(sprintf "^%s[-_](%s|%s)" p.Style p.ColorCode p.ColorName, RegexOptions.Singleline + RegexOptions.Compiled)
for i in 1..30 do
    if regex.IsMatch(sprintf "code-%d" i) then printfn "%A" i
```

Comment: Thank you much for your response. I will try your regex suggestion for sure, and will post results!

Comment: Quick update. I ran a sample of 1k x 1k arrays. To my surprise, the regex actually performed rather slow. On the 1k sample, the original code took less than one second (.608ms) while the regex took 35 secs.

These are the following combinations I tried with the regex:

outter Array.Parallel.map on Inner Array.Parallel.map,
outter Array.Parallel.map on Inner Seq.tryPick,
regex compiled,
regex uncompiled.

I'm off to implement your second suggestion of comparing tuples. Will post results.

Comment: the dictionary is of course the answer! does the parallel have any significant impact? these arent exactly long running jobs, so the cost of setting up the parallel will be relatively high!

Comment: i’ll have a go if i get a chance

Comment: In my computer there is not much difference but maybe in a computer with many cores...

Comment: @MrD you are right in both cases. Parallel didn't have a significant impact. And the dictionary "will" be the answer. I'm trying that now... will post results.

Comment: AMAZING :)

Works incredibly fast! Thank you x 50k